# Insert a number of rows equal to a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a code go through each row in my data and insert a number of rows equal to the value in column C of the same row when it moves to a new unique entry.

I managed to get together some code that will do this but only 1 row as seen here:

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()
   Dim lRow As Long
   For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
      If Cells(lRow, "A") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "A") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
   Next lRow
End Sub
```

The problem is that I need to count how many times the value appears in column A and then make it insert a number of rows to a total of what is housed in C. So if the value is already in A 5 times, but C has a value of 8, I need to insert 3 rows after the 5 duplicate values.

Is there a way to get this to insert a number of rows equal to whatever value is currently housed in column C of the same row? It is important to know that the value in C could be 0 which would mean that no row would be inserted.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304181 offers a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification that might get you there...

```
  Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()
       Dim lRow As Long
       For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 10 Step -1
            If Cells(lRow, "A") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "A") And Cells(lRow, "C") > 0 Then
                Rows(lRow).Resize(Cells(lRow, "C")).Insert
            End If
       Next lRow
    End Sub
```